# Listening to two ports simultaneously in Java server using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I am building a simple Java server which simultaneously listens for client request on two ports simultaneously using two ServerSocket instances. Here is the code for Server:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Socket1 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSock=new ServerSocket(5000);
            while(true)
            {
                Socket sock=serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                String text="Welcome to Port 5000";
                writer.println(text);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

class Socket2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket serverSock=new ServerSocket(3000);
            while(true)
            {
                Socket sock=serverSock.accept();
                PrintWriter writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                String text="Welcome to Port 3000";
                writer.println(text);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}

public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Socket1 s1=new Socket1();
        Socket2 s2=new Socket2();
        Thread t1=new Thread(s1);
        Thread t2=new Thread(s2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Now code for Client1:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader=new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            String text=reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(text);
            reader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Client2 contains the same code as Client1, the only difference being that it tries to connect to port 3000. 
Now, I execute Server.java first using command prompt. While the server blocks, I open two separate command prompts and execute Client1.java on one command prompt and Client2.java on the other command prompt. But, both clients go to blocking state and I get no output. Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrintWriter is buffered by defaut. Add a `writer.flush()` (or even better a `close()` since you're not using the stream anymore) after `writer.println()`.